# How to create a custom mask image for back buttons in iOS7

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, ios7, mask

From the [dox](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html):

> - If you want to use a custom image to replace the default chevron, you also need to create a custom mask image. iOS 7 uses the mask to
>     make the previous screen’s title appear to emerge from—or disappear
>     into—the chevron during navigation transitions. To learn about the
>     properties that control the Back button and mask image, see
>     UINavigationBar Class Reference.

In UINavigationBar Class Reference:

> backIndicatorImage
>
> The image shown beside the back button. @property(nonatomic, retain)
>   UIImage *backIndicatorImage Discussion
>
> If you want to customize the back indicator image, you must also set
>   backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 7.0 and later.
> ```
>
> See Also
>
> ```
>   @property backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage
> ```
>
> Declared In UINavigationBar.h backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage
>
> The image used as a mask for content during push and pop transitions.
>   @property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage
>   Discussion
>
> If you want to customize the back indicator image, you must also set
>   backIndicatorImage. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 7.0 and later.
> ```
>
> See Also
>
> ```
>   @property backIndicatorImage
> ```
>
> Declared In UINavigationBar.h

Excuse my ignorance, but the information provided does not tell me much at all.

Is there a Cocoa class that will make a mask with the desired image? Or do I need to provide the frame, arcs, and such? Or do I just make a black outline of my image in an editor?

Comment: "Customizing Your App’s Appearance for iOS 7" session from WWDC 2013 explains the meaning of both of those parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think this is what you are looking for

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = [UIImage yourImage];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = [UIImage yourImage];
```

Comment: This is not hard to figure out (the documentation mentions it) but how am I supposed to provide the image? Does it work with transparency or black/white colors, etc. I've tried a PNG and it just acts as a white rectangle that covers the content: http://cl.ly/image/0N1V2L181i3t
Edit: kowal's answer mentions the solution

Comment: See below, reply from Kowal. The transitionMaskImage as shown in this example should be different from the indicator image and not the same, otherwise the text will appear clipped during transitions.

Answer (score 38):

The `backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage` is the visibility mask.

In the mask image:

- the pixels with the `alpha = 0` will be **covering** the moving title during navigation transitions;
- the pixels with the `alpha = 1` will be **transparent** for the moving title during navigation transitions.

So if you want to provide the same visibility behavior as in the native back indicator, you can use the images (utf-8 signs) similar to those below:

1. Back indicator image:〱
2. Back indicator mask: ◀ (only the text under the black part will be visible)

Answer (score -2):

this is what i did and works perfectly

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 40, 40)];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *barBackButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBackButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

and "popViewController" looks like this

```
-(void)popViewController{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}